# Docker start Container after reboot

Tags: docker

Hi guys I have the issue that a docker container always shuts down after reboot.
i tried these commands but it didn't help:

[image: Code i used]

How is this possible? thanks (Im running docker on kali linux)

Comment: you have to docker login ... use ` docker login ` command

Comment: I don't recognize `code` as a normal Linux command, and the PNG file you link to won't be runnable either.  What command did you actually run?

Comment: Hi, please *Do Not* post your code as an image, post is as a text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community the Problem is already solved???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the docker run command incorrectly by trying to run an already running container. The error certainly wasn't very helpful. You could try the below.

sudo docker update --restart=always de04ffdeaae2

If you want to stop the container at anytime do;

sudo docker update --restart=no de04ffdeaae2
sudo docker stop de04ffdeaae2

To restart;

docker ps (to get the image name or ID);
docker run -d --restart always your-image-name/or-id